# optimal method to find first available bit

Tags: c

Given an array of unsinged integers(4 octets each), what's the optimal way of finding first element with atleast one '0' bit and it's index from LSB.

e.g: where n = 9

```
unsinged int uIntArray[] = {
    0xffffffff,
    0xffffffff,
    0xffffffff,
    0xffffffff,
    0xffffff9f,
    0x00000000,
    0x00000000,
    0x00000000,
    0x00000000,
};
```

Ans:

```
element's index = 4
bit's index = 4
```

I could only think of :

```
int main (void)
{
    bool found_f = false;
    int n = 9;  //our test case value
    unsigned int uIntArray[] = {
        0xffffffff,
        0xffffffff,
        0xffffffff,
        0xffffffff,
        0xffffff8f,
        0x00000000,
        0x00000000,
        0x00000000,
        0x00000000,
    };  

    unsigned int uIntBits [32] = {
        1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128,
            256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192, 16384, 32768,
            65536, 131072, 262144, 524288, 1048576, 2097152, 4194304, 8388608,
            16777216, 33554432, 67108864, 134217728, 268435456, 536870912, 1073741824, 2147483648
    };      

    unsigned int idx, jdx;
    int ele_idx = -1; 
    int bit_idx = -1;

    for (idx =0; idx < n; idx ++) {
        if (uIntArray[idx] < UINT_MAX) { /* our candidate */
            for (jdx =0; jdx < 32; jdx ++)  {
                if ((uIntBits[jdx] & uIntArray[idx])) {
                    ele_idx = idx; 
                    bit_idx = jdx;
                    found_f = true;
                    break;
                }   
            }   
        }   
        if(found_f) {
            break;
        }   
    }   
    fprintf (stderr, "\nEleIdx[%d] BitIdx[%d]\n", ele_idx, bit_idx);
    return 0;
}
```

is there any better way to do it?

Comment: Your logic can be tightened up a bit. The `found_f` is unnecessary. The array is not required either.

Comment: Firstly, the correct answer for your first array is `(4, 5)` and not `(4, 4)` as you claim. Secondly, your actual code sample uses `0xffffff8f` value in the array instead of the original `0xffffff9f`, in which case the correct answer is indeed `(4, 4)`. Don't confuse people by mixing up examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The index of the least significant `0` in `x` is the index of the least significant `1` in `~x`. In order to find the latter you just need to count the trailing zeros in `~x`. There are quite a few ways to do it, see here http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ZerosOnRightLinear

Using the last method (based on DeBruijn sequence), the search would look as

```
static const unsigned MultiplyDeBruijnBitPosition[32] = 
{
  0, 1, 28, 2, 29, 14, 24, 3, 30, 22, 20, 15, 25, 17, 4, 8, 
  31, 27, 13, 23, 21, 19, 16, 7, 26, 12, 18, 6, 11, 5, 10, 9
};

for (idx = 0; idx < n; idx ++)
  if (uIntArray[idx] < UINT_MAX)
    break;

if (idx < n) {
  unsigned v = ~uIntArray[idx];
  int bit_idx = MultiplyDeBruijnBitPosition[((v & -v) * 0x077CB531u) >> 27];
  fprintf(stderr, "\nEleIdx[%d] BitIdx[%d]\n", idx, bit_idx);
}
```

Comment: Timed a test program on my desktop:

Arraysize 100 & desired element was on index 95

1 - MyOwn 
 Total Time taken [65535] Iterations [0.027451512] Seconds 
 
2 - based on DeBruijn sequence(IMPRESSIVE)
 Total Time taken [65535] Iterations [0.019844761] Seconds 
 
3 - below one 4 bytes at a time; & narrowing within 4 after finding the candidate group
 Total Time taken [65535] Iterations [0.055722110] Seconds 

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it faster by using larger datatypes. So instead of testing if each `int` is `0xffffffff`, you can go with 64-bit integers and test against `0xffffffffffffffff`.

If you're willing to vectorize, you can do 128-bits (SSE) or 256-bits (AVX) at a time.

In all cases, watch your data alignment. If you don't align, it either won't work, or will make it slower.

To take it one final step, you can actually unroll the loop and test multiple words/vectors at a time. This will give you better IPC. Only when you find any zero do you go through the mess of narrowing down which bit it is.

EDIT:

To illustrate this last point, you can do this: (I've omitted the cleanup code in case `idx % 4 != 0`)

```
for (idx =0; idx < n; idx += 4) {
    unsigned int test = uIntArray[idx];
    test &= uIntArray[idx + 1];
    test &= uIntArray[idx + 2];
    test &= uIntArray[idx + 3];

    if (test < UINT_MAX){
        //  Find which bit it is.

    }
}
```

Except you can do it on larger datatypes. (like SSE/AVX vectors)

This will make finding the region of the first 0 much faster, but narrowing on the exact bit will be a bit more expensive. So this approach is better if your datasize is large.

Comment: @Mystical: Although vectorization and loop unrolling are good ways to make the code run faster, not that it is wrong to do it "by hand" but do you think in this case it has to be done manually? On most modern compilers we have options available for vectorization & they will do loops unrolling in cases like these ( probably unroll loop in steps larger than 4 :) ) when they generate the machine code... just want to know your take on this

Comment: @another.anon.coward: Actually most compilers will not unroll this loop because it has conditional side-effects (`ele_idx = idx`).

Comment: Ah missed that! Sorry ... got your name wrong the first time and thanks a lot for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

To find the first element you can observe that if the number *didn't* have a `0` bit then it must be `0xff..ff` so instead of explicitly checking each bit, you can simply compare it to `0xff..ff`.

To find the least significant bit of that number I believe you will still have to check each bit.

Comment: That formula produces the rightmost 1-bit, not the rightmost 0-bit.

Comment: @cnicutar I was editing it just then but I realised that it got the value of the right most bit instead of the position. Still, this significantly simplifies finding the first element with a `0` bit.

Answer (score 1):

The following code seems to work nicely, using the `~x & (x + 1)` test from another (now deleted) answer and extending it.  Not sure why the other answer was deleted.

```
/* Return the position of the first clear bit in the array,
 * or -1 if none found.
 *  arr:  array of uint32_t to search
 *  sz:   number of elements in arr
 */
int findClearBit(uint32_t *arr, int sz)
{
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
    if (~arr[i]) {
      switch (~arr[i] & (arr[i] + 1)) {
        case 1 << 31:  return (i * 32) + 31;
        case 1 << 30:  return (i * 32) + 30;
        case 1 << 29:  return (i * 32) + 29;
        case 1 << 28:  return (i * 32) + 28;
        case 1 << 27:  return (i * 32) + 27;
        case 1 << 26:  return (i * 32) + 26;
        case 1 << 25:  return (i * 32) + 25;
        case 1 << 24:  return (i * 32) + 24;
        case 1 << 23:  return (i * 32) + 23;
        case 1 << 22:  return (i * 32) + 22;
        case 1 << 21:  return (i * 32) + 21;
        case 1 << 20:  return (i * 32) + 20;
        case 1 << 19:  return (i * 32) + 19;
        case 1 << 18:  return (i * 32) + 18;
        case 1 << 17:  return (i * 32) + 17;
        case 1 << 16:  return (i * 32) + 16;
        case 1 << 15:  return (i * 32) + 15;
        case 1 << 14:  return (i * 32) + 14;
        case 1 << 13:  return (i * 32) + 13;
        case 1 << 12:  return (i * 32) + 12;
        case 1 << 11:  return (i * 32) + 11;
        case 1 << 10:  return (i * 32) + 10;
        case 1 << 9:   return (i * 32) + 9;
        case 1 << 8:   return (i * 32) + 8;
        case 1 << 7:   return (i * 32) + 7;
        case 1 << 6:   return (i * 32) + 6;
        case 1 << 5:   return (i * 32) + 5;
        case 1 << 4:   return (i * 32) + 4;
        case 1 << 3:   return (i * 32) + 3;
        case 1 << 2:   return (i * 32) + 2;
        case 1 << 1:   return (i * 32) + 1;
        case 1:        return (i * 32);
        default:       return -1;
      }
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: very close to De Bruijn's sequence; per my test(on my desktop in [2097120] Iterations) above function is lagging only by 0.4% at max. Above takes [0.636051089] Seconds while De Bruijn's sequence does it in [0.633582442]. Are these two same algos in disguise!!! Thank you very much Dmitri.